# Draw lines from db in asp.net on google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some lat,lng coordinates which for drawing polylines that come from database. I use asp.net c# and sql server. the sample code from [gmaps](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/) below and it has path as string in html side.
How can I call/write lat,lngs from db from code behind to here? How is it working?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333,
        click: function(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      });

      path = [[-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184], [-12.05449279282314, -77.03024273281858], [-12.055122327623378, -77.03039293652341], [-12.075917129727586, -77.02764635449216], [-12.07635776902266, -77.02792530422971], [-12.076819390363665, -77.02893381481931], [-12.088527520066453, -77.0241058385925], [-12.090814532191756, -77.02271108990476]];

      map.drawPolyline({
        path: path,
        strokeColor: '#131540',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 6
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the [Google Maps .NET Control for V3 Maps](http://www.reimers.dk/files/google-maps-.net-control-for-v3-maps). This control will allow you to work with your Google Map from code-behind.

This control has a `GooglePolyline`, which equates to your intended behavior in your posted script code.

Read [Adding Overlays to Maps](http://www.reimers.dk/tutorials/adding-overlays-to-maps) for a quick tutorial on using the `GooglePolyline` object.

Comment: Thanks, is this the only way I have to do it?
If I don't want to use somethign external dll, etc?..

Comment: No, this is not the only way you can do it; I was thinking that you wanted a code-behind (server-side) solution, but maybe I was wrong in that assumption. You can have a client-side solution that calls to the server to get database information via AJAX calls to an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, web service, etc.

Comment: I could not explain myself correctly I guess :)
Client side solution may work fine, just I do not know how to bind two sides. how can I do that with Ajax or any way?

Comment: Read [Using jQuery to call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for an explanation.

Comment: great, hope it helps you out. If you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer and/or up-vote the answer when you have enough reputation to do so. :-)